# Cannot stream mp3 in Android. Error: 'Unable to play this type of audio file'

Tags: java, android, audio-streaming

I am using a WebViewClient to display a list of .mp3 files. After clicking on an mp3 file url, I want Android to pop up the 'Complete Action Using' menu that allows the user to select which Media Player to stream the mp3 from.

With the following code I am able to launch the 'Complete Action Using' menu and am able to select a media player. Unfortunately, every single media player spits out their own version of the "unable to play file" error message.

Do you see any errors in the following code? Thank you!

```
private class MapWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {        
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        if (url.endsWith(".mp3")) {

            Intent intent = new Intent();  
            intent.setAction(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            File file = null;
            try {
                file = new File(url);
                intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(file), "audio/*");
                startActivity(intent);
            } catch (NullPointerException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


            return true;
        } else {
            return super.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view, url);
        }
    }
```

Comment: sounds more like an encoding issue with your mp3 to me.

Comment: is this okay? `file = new File(url);` how can you create a file from URL?

Comment: Try setting the content type to `audio/mpeg`.  Also, are you sure your file is MP3?

Comment: I'm working with Andy (OP) on this project. The files are definitely MP3.
According to this page (specifically "constructor summary" section): http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/File.html we can construct a file from a string containing a pathname or a URI.